# C: write file from kernel-module correct this way?

Tags: c, file, kernel-module, fwrite

I try to copy/write pcm-bytes (from ALSA-buffer) from the kernel-space into a file within a kernel-module (LKM).

The file got's written and the size looks ok for me, but because it's PCM-data I can't see if it's correct (raw audio data, not readable).

My audio-players (MPlayer="Invalid seek to negative position ffffffffffffffff!", VLC, Foobar2000) fail to play my written file so I think I have a mistake in my code.

When I open the file via SCITE I see many many "NUL" and other cryted stuff (bytes ;).

Maybe one of you find a bug?

I have this script:

```
unsigned char *dma_area; // this is the source, an mmapped-area
int pcm_offset_bytes; // the actual offset in the dma_area
int size_bytes; // the amount of bytes to copy
struct file *target_file; // the target-file


int ret; // used in write-process below
int wrote = 0; // used in write-process below
mm_segment_t fs;
void *data; // dma_area + pcm_offset_bytes

// (..) calculate offset and size

// open the target file
target_file = filp_open("/dev/snd/pcmC0D0p_output", (O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_WRONLY), (S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO));

data = dma_area + pcm_offset_bytes


fs = get_fs();
set_fs (get_ds ());

if (!target_file || !target_file->f_op || !target_file->f_op->write) {
    LOGI("something's missing\n");
    return -EIO;
}

// loop until every byte is written
while (size_bytes > 0) {

    ret = target_file->f_op->write(target_file, (char *)data, size_bytes, &target_file->f_pos);

    LOGI ("wrote %d bytes to target_file@%p, return %d\n", size_bytes, target_file, ret);
    if (ret <= 0)
        goto done;

    size_bytes -= ret;
    data += ret;
    wrote += ret;
}

ret = wrote;

done:
    set_fs(fs);
    LOGI("result %d\n", ret);
```

Comment: This looks correct. I'd guess that the media player just doesn't understand the file because it's raw PCM. Try stealing the RIFF header from an existing wav file and prepending it to the file, then try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you aren't "supposed to" write to files within the kernel.

For the more proper question of how to play headerless raw pcm, you can use the import function of audacity.

Or use aplay

```
aplay some_file -t raw -f S16_LE -c 2 -r 44100
```

With whatever parameters are appropriate.

Comment: Hey, yes I know that it's not good to write files in kernel-space. It's just to test the currenct functionality. I will try the aplay-tip, but it's not that easy because the module is on android (no aplay). But maybe in my virtal machine.